# Getting ValueError during assignment of rows in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have the following piece of code:

```
norm_embed = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(embeddings, embeddings), 1))
comparison = tf.greater(norm_embed, tf.constant(1.))
cond_assignment = tf.assign(embeddings, tf.where(comparison, embeddings/norm_embed, embeddings))
```

What I'm trying to do is that I have a matrix `embeddings` of `[V, 1]` shape. And I want to normalize those rows where norm of a row is greater than 1.

However, I get ValueError:

> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 2 and 11202 for
>   'truediv_1' (op: 'RealDiv') with input shapes: [11202,2], [11202].

I understand that matrix `norm_embed` has `[V]` shape, but during division `[V, k]` matrix by vector `[V]` the latter should be broadcasted. I don't understand why it's not happening. I also tried to reshape the vector to `[V, 1]` shape but it didn't help.

Why I receive ValueError during normalization? Maybe other ways to normalize rows when they exceed value?

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors with the code.

First, we need reshape `norm_embed` to have two dimensions:

```
norm_embed = tf.reshape(norm_embed, [V, 1])
```

Second, we need to reshape comparison operator to have only 1 dimension.

```
comparison = tf.reshape(comparison, [vocabulary_size])
```

After that code works:

```
norm_embed = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(embeddings, embeddings), 1))
norm_embed = tf.reshape(norm_embed, [V, 1])
comparison = tf.greater(norm_embed, tf.constant(1.))
comparison = tf.reshape(comparison, [V])
replacement = tf.where(comparison, embeddings/norm_embed, embeddings)
cond_assignment = tf.assign(embeddings, replacement)
```